# Displaying Products of a particular category in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am building an e-commerce project using Laravel 5.4, I have got 2 tables which have the following columns:

**categories**: id, name , timestamps

**Products**: id , name, price, description, size , image , category_id , timestamps

The two tables are interlinked via **one to many** relationship(One Category has many products). I am uploading images and storing inside public/images folder in my Laravel app while the image name is stored in the database. When I upload everything is working fine, but when I pull images of a **particular category** so as to display in a view called **Front.blade.php** which is controlled by **frontcontroller**, I get blank fields(it doesnt pull the images). Please assist?

**Category model**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');   
    }

}
```

**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'desctiption' , 'size', 'category_id', 'image'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

**Products Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $formInput[]=$request->image;

       //validation
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required',
            'size'=>'required',
            'description' => 'required|min:12',
            'price'=>'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'image'=>'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif|max:100'
        ]);

        $image=$request->image;
        if($image){
            $imageName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move('images',$imageName);
            $formInput['image']=$imageName;
        }

        //Instantiate a new Project called Product
        $product = new Product;

        //Add the products to the Object
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->price = $request->price;.
        $product->image = $imageName;
        $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $product->size = $request->size;

        //Save all the items to the database
        $product->save();

    }
```

**FrontController**

```
public function index(){
        $items = Category::find(6)->products()->where('image' , true)->get();

        return view('front.index')->withItems($items);
    }
```

**Front.blade.php**

```
@foreach($items as $item)
            <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$item->image) }}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: You're looking for items who have an image value of `true` that's not a valid image name though. Perhaps you meant to do `whereNotNull("image")` ?

Comment: @apokryfos  Wow, it works fine Thank you so much, what if I want to add price of that particular image from the price column in products table and store both in one variable the pass to the view, how can I do that,,?

Comment: If you want to add it as a condition you can add an addtional where e.g. `whereNotNull("image")->where("price","<",<some number>)->get()`

Comment: @apokryfos   Ok,, I get you,, can I use the where method with one parameter (in this case the price column from the database) cause I want to pass the price of that particular image

Answer (score 0):

Replace where() clause with orwhere() as below to only return where images == true

```
    public function index(){

        $items = Category::find(6)->products()->orWhere('image','<>','')->get();

        return view('front.index', compact('items'));
    }
```